# Issue finding configuration file in javafxports android project

Tags: java, android, javafx, config, javafxports

I am trying to build an android application from a javaFX project using javafxports. Currently I am facing a problem when installing on mobile device and starting it, it throws a ConfigurationException.[image] This is the code using the file:

```
public class AppConfig extends XMLConfiguration {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 550015250032006413L;
private static AppConfig instance;
private static String configFile = "src/main/assets/config.xml";

// Singleton initialiser
static {
    instance = new AppConfig(configFile);
}

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param fileName Configuration file name.
 */
private AppConfig(String fileName) {
    init(fileName);
}

/**
 * Initialize the class.
 *
 * @param fileName Configuration file name.
 */
private void init(String fileName) {
    setFileName(fileName);
    try {
        load();
    } catch (ConfigurationException configEx) {
        configEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'



buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5'
    }
}



repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}

mainClassName = "com.example.amladzhov.irisandroid.sample.Client.StartApplication"

jfxmobile {
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }

        dependencies {

            compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.6'
            compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-exec:1.3'
            compile 'commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.5'
            compile 'org.apache.axis:axis:1.4'
            compile 'javax.xml.rpc:javax.xml.rpc-api:1.1.1'
            //compile 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2'
            compile 'org.jdom:jdom:2.0.2'
            compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
            compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.3'
        }
    }
}
```

The file is located in

```
src/main/assets/config.xml
```

Comment: First, you can't expect that the xml file will be placed under "src" on runtime; second, the `assets` folder under `main` is not exported to android. While there is a `src/android/assets` folder that you can use, you should place the xml file under `src/main/resources` and then load the file using `getClass().getResources("/config.xml").toExternalForm()`.

Comment: Hello José, can you please tell me where I should  put the code: getClass().getResources("/config.xml").toExternalForm()

Comment: If you just need the url of the file as a string, you could do `String configFile = AppConfig.class.getResources("/config.xml").toExternalForm()`, where `config.xml` is placed at `/src/main/resources/config.xml`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect that the xml file will be placed under a `src` folder on runtime.

But notice that the `assets` folder under the `main` package is not exported to Android, so the file won't be available in any way.

While there is a `src/android/assets` folder that you can use to place resources required for Android, that requires Android API to read it.

The best option is placing the `xml` file under `src/main/resources` and then loading the file like you do regularly in Java using `getResources()`.

So place the file under `src/main/resources/config.xml`, and replace this:

```
private static String configFile = "src/main/assets/config.xml";
```

with this:

```
private static String configFile = AppConfig.class.getResources("/config.xml").toExternalForm();
```